# SQL Server: Insert INTO Statement syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why  does not the following `INSERT` statement  give any error?

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(id INT,name VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO Table1(xx.id,yyyy.name) Values (1,'A')
```

Why does the above statement ignore `xx.` and `yyyy.`? What does this imply ?

Comment: what are the xx. and yyy. supposed to represent? INSERT INTO (id,name) VALUES (1,'A')

Comment: As the OP points out, this doesn't generate an error:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/057c5.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the below query also.

```
INSERT INTO Table11(xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.id,yy.yy.yy.yy.yy.yy.yy.yy.name) 
Values (1,'A')
```

It also got worked. Usually we use alias for joins. As I know, For Insert query Using alias near table name is restricted in sql. In the case of column name, the query use only the string next to the last Dot(.).

I conclude it as, The Insert query don't care about the string prefixed to the column name separated by Dot(.).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that the database engine is ignoring the name space as the query's scope is limited to the Table's scope when dealing with INSERT INTO. When it comes to say UPDATE where multiple tables can be part of the scope, the below would fail. Don't know why this happens but if I were to guess, probably all values to the left of the last period'.' is ignored

If you analyze the execution plan for the below query

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(id INT,name VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO Table1(Table2.dbo.id,...................name) Values (1,'A')
```

AS

```
INSERT INTO [Table1]([id],[name]) Values(@1,@2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This implies the namespace of something...

For example:

```
SELECT object.id, object.name FROM table object WHERE object.name = 'Foo';

                                          / \
                                          | |
                            object is the name space for the table.
```

And if you haven't a namespace created the query fails.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the syntax you are using generally means table.column
So in other words you are trying to insert into Table1 but declaring columns from other tables.

You should do something like this

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(id INT,name VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO Table1(id,name) Values (1,'A')
```

Comment: I think the question is not how it *should* be but why the statement from the question works despite the incorrect syntax.